# Error en XAMPP - phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Tengo el siguiente error en mi localhost en Xampp y phpMyAdmin .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Error de phpMyAdmin]

La última vez que tuve un error similar tuve que reinstalar todo Xampp. Les agradecería su ayuda porque no quiero borrar todo lo que he trabajado en mi localhost.

He intentado modificar el usuario root y las contraseñas pero nada ha funcionado.

Mil gracias de antemano.

Comment: No necesitas borrar todo en tu localhost,  xampp te pregunta que si quieres tambien eliminar los datos que haya en la carpeta htdocs o si los quieres conservar.

Comment: Abre una consola de mysql, sino te deja acceder, borra el mysql, si te deja acceder, copia la carpeta htdocs a otro sitio a modo de backup, y desistala el xampp.